# Передача параметров из Ajax.ActionLink в контроллер и возврат представления обратно

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Пишу вьюху:

```
@model TradingPlaces.Models.Construction
.....
<div id="results">
     @Html.Partial("ImageUpload")   
</div>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete Image", "DeleteImage", new { house = @Model }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" })
```

по клику на экшнлинк выполняю передачу на контроллер:

```
public ActionResult DeleteImage(Construction house)
{
     byte[] imageData = null;
     house.Image = imageData;
     return PartialView("ImageUpload",house);
}
```

обработчик возвращается в контроллер, но почему-то в параметре **house** оказывается пустая модель. поэтому собственно 1й вопрос:

1) Как правильно передать параметр из вьюхи в контроллер, для последующей его обработки?

Далее я хотел бы обновлять данные в `<div id="results">`, возвращая в страницу новое новое частичное представление, но `return PartialView("ImageUpload",house)` просто открывает мне частичное представление вместо старой страницы. собственно второй вопрос:

2) Как правильно возвратить частичное представление перегрузив только нужный мне `<div id="results">` без перегрузки всей страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что метод ActionLink не передает параметры в контроллер. Он всего лишь геренирует ссылку, которая будет отрендерена в результирующий html. Общепринятого (стандартного) метода представления объектов C# в виде html/параметров ссылки нет, так что ActionLink ограничивается простым вызовом `model.ToString()`. Ваш класс, скорее всего, `ToString()` не переопределяет, так что на выходе вы получаете что-то вроде:

```
<a href="/DeleteImage?House=TradingPlaces.Models.Construction" />
```

Полноценный объект House, как вы того хотите, передать через ссылку нельзя - да и не имеет смысла в вашем случае. Ваш метод, судя по всему, должен очищать картинку у House, хранимого где-то в базе. Для этого достаточно передать идентификатор (уникальный номер) дома:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete Image", "DeleteImage", new { houseId = @Model.ID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" })
```

и очистить значение в контроллере:

```
public ActionResult DeleteImage(int houseId)
{
     var house = GetHouseFromDatabase(houseId);
     house.Image = null;
     SaveHouseToDatabase(house); // сохранить null в базу

     return PartialView("ImageUpload",house);
}
```