# Передать параметр из представления в контроллер ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть представление:

В качестве модели оно использует список View-Model.
View-Model представляет собой модель, очищенную от служебных полей (ключи, внешние ключи)  - сложный объект, содержащий в себе в числе прочего список объектов помельче:

```
@model List<BusinessLayer.ViewModels.VMs.SiteVM>

<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>  Url сайта </th>
        <th> Дата/время измерения </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.SiteAdress, "ShowDataFromHistory", "History", new { chosenvm = item })
            </td>
            <td>@item.LaunchTime</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Я хочу вывести таблицу, которая будет содержать 2 поля View-model (с таблицей все нормально). При этом, по клику пользователь должен иметь возможность получить подробную информацию о вью-модели.
По сути, мне нужно пробросить выбранную View-model в другое представление без изменений, где она выступит в качестве модели и там вывести список вложенных объектов.
Я хотел сделать это через контроллер:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ShowDataFromHistory ( SiteVM chosenvm)
    {
        string aux = "Вспомогательная строка для точки останова";
        return View ("ShowDataFromHistory",chosenvm);
    }
```

Но [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480600/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-ajax-actionlink-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0) пишут, что  используя `Html.ActionLink` у меня ничего не выйдет.
Но и так, как там рекомендуют (передать `int Id` ) у меня сразу не получится, так как я убрал ключи, а идентификатором у меня служит дата (типа `DateTime`).
Передать дату даже как строку, тоже не получается, на входе в метод контроллера - `null` (здесь приведена первичная версия еще до экспериментов).

В связи с этим - вопрос:
Каким образом мне пробросить выбранный объект в другое представление?  Я не связан использованием именно `ActionLink`, просто не знаю более подходящего механизма. Представление , в которое нужно пробросить выбранную `ViewModel`   может находиться как в том же контроллере, так и в другом -  здесь у меня пока есть выбор. Скорее всего в том же.
Не хотелось бы использовать  без  крайней необходимости `ViewData`, `ViewBag` и т.п. - меня учили, что это плохая практика, а я пытаюсь учиться сразу хорошей.

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink(item.SiteAdress, "ShowDataFromHistory", "History", new { chosenvm = item })` - посмотрите в браузере ("View page source") чему равен `href` этого анкера - Вы удивитесь

Comment: @Igor:  http://localhost:1126/History/ShowDataFromHistory?Length=7. Уже удивлялся. Совершенно не понял откуда взялось Length=7. Единственное что подходит по длине - "History"

Comment: @Igor: Точнее сказать href  = /History/ShowDataFromHistory?Length=7. Причем во всех элементах одинаковый.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4 `@Html.ActionLink(item.SiteAdress, "ShowDataFromHistory", "History", new { chosenvm = item }, null)`

Comment: Но даже так у Вас нарушена логика - Вы хотите сериализовать в url объект `item`, a в методе контроллера ожидаете весь `SiteVM`

Comment: @Igor:Почему нарушена логика? Модель во вьюхе - List<SiteVM>  в методе хочу увидеть SiteVM, т.е. элемент List<>.

Comment: @Igor: Спасибо за ссылку, вечером попробую.

Comment: я бы сделал в одном представлении все. 2 слоя, в одном список всех viewModel, во втором подробная информация о первом экземпляре viewModel. второй слой изначально скрыт. при нажатии на элемент с помощью javascript первый слой скрывается а второй показывается и в него передается выбранная модель. контроллер не нужен и страница не перезагружается.